# How do I measure frequency of an audio file into an array?

Tags: fft, audio, frequency, stft

So I know how to plot fft the audio file within Matlab and a window pops up. My question is, what next? I want to know how to go about measuring the frequency(s). I have two similar audio files, of two people saying the same thing, and i want to see if there's a relationship (correlation) between their voices in terms of frequencies and speed (bpm)

Comment: Welcome to DSP.SE!  As the message above says, we need more information to try to figure out what you need to be answered. You have your signal `x`, you have its FFT `X = fft(x)`.  Why did you take the FFT? What information / processing are you trying to do?  Your question doesn't make this clear.

Comment: I want to know how to go about measuring the frequency(s). I have two similar audio files, of two people saying the same thing, and i want to see if there's a relationship (correlation) between their voices in terms of frequencies and speed (bpm).

Comment: Ok! Can you please edit your question to add this info?

Comment: Done. Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Speech processing is a very long and detailed topic, but let's make a start.

**Correlation**

This probably won't work, but the first thing you can try is [cross-correlation of the signals.](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/xcorr.html)

```
xc = xcorr(speaker_1, speaker_2);
```

Note that really all you may get out of this is the delay between each sample (if you're lucky).

You might also get **some** level of correlation coefficient by taking the peak value of

```
xc = xcorr(speaker_1/std(speaker_1), speaker_2/std(speaker2));
```

**Where Next?**

If that doesn't work (I'm not hopeful), you will need to look at lots of other options:

- Blocking the data into frames
- Finding features within these frames ([LPCs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_predictive_coding), etc.).
- Using some method to time-align these between speech samples ([DTW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_time_warping))
- Finding some measure of "likeness" between the time-aligned features.